# how to map a column that contains multiple strings according to a dictionary in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe in which one column contains strings separated by comma. I want map the columns according to a dictionary.

For example:

```
dfm = pd.DataFrame({'Idx': np.arange(4), 'Names': ['John,Mary', 'Mike', 'Mike,Joe,Mary', 'John']})
mask = {'John':'1', 'Mary':'2','Joe':'3','Mike':'4'}
```

Desired Output:

```
    Idx Names
0   0   1,2
1   1   4
2   2   4,3,2
3   3   1
```

What's the best way to achieve that? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```py
>>> dfm.Names.apply(lambda x: ','.join([mask[i] for i in x.split(',')]))
0      1,2
1        4
2    4,3,2
3        1
Name: Names, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to pass a function to the `.str.replace` function that we can use in this case

```
dfm.Names.str.replace('\w+(?=,|$)', lambda m: mask.get(m.group(0)))
```

Using this, it is possible to create a new data frame as such:

```
pd.DataFrame({
    'Idx': dfm.Idx, 
    'Names': dfm.Names.str.replace('\w+(?=,|$)', lambda m: mask.get(m.group(0)))
})
# outputs:
   Idx  Names
0    0    1,2
1    1      4
2    2  4,3,2
3    3      1
```